# JavaFX - Border radius <-> Background color

Tags: java, css, javafx, gridpane

If I add `-fx-border-radius` and `-fx-border-width` CSS to a simple GridPane, in its corner the background will not be "cut down".

The CSS:

```
.payload {
    -fx-hgap: 20px;
    -fx-padding: 40px;

    -fx-background-color: #2969c0;

    -fx-border-radius: 50px;
    -fx-border-width: 5px;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 10, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The picture about the result:
[image: picture link]

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to add the radius property as well to define the background fill. Otherwise it will asume a zero value, as shown in your picture.

You can check the CSS specs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).

You just need to add the `-fx-background-radius` property:

```
.payload {
    -fx-hgap: 20px;
    -fx-padding: 40px;

    -fx-background-color: #2969c0;
    -fx-background-radius: 50px;

    -fx-border-radius: 50px;
    -fx-border-width: 5px;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 10, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

[image: background radius]