# JavaFX how to "crop" graphics to buttons

Tags: java, button, javafx

Essentially, what I want is to create a `Button` with a cropped graphic. Cropped in the sense of, the `Image` is in the back, and the `Button` is a hole, showing the `Graphic`. As of now, it looks like[image: Failed Attempt]

However I want the graphic to fit the button, even if its bigger, to just get cut off. My current code is along the lines of

```
Image image = new Image(Main.class.getResource("/texture.png").toExternalForm());
yesButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a background using javafx css:

```
Button button = new Button("Button");
button.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/texture.png')");
```

Or programmatically with [Background](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html) by `setBackground`:

```
Image image = new Image(Main.class.getResource("/texture.png").toExternalForm());
BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(image, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.AUTO);
Background background = new Background(backgroundImage);

Button button = new Button("Button");
button.setBackground(background);
```

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the shape of the button? I.e. the curve instead of the sharp edges from the images?

Comment: You should look at questions with border styling issues, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20490028/3426515 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/43557722/3426515