# could not add rounded corners for hbox of JavaFX? How to resolve this?

Tags: java, javafx, hbox

I am trying to put rounded courders for the hbox but couldn't do it.

how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.!

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      VBox root = new VBox();
      root.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,0));//top,Right,Bottom,Left
      root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#00BFFF");

      HBox child1=new HBox();
      child1.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,40,0));//top,Right,Bottom,Left
      //child1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FFFFFF");
       child1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FFFFFF;"+ "-fx-border-radius: 50 50 50 50;");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557722/javafx-border-radius-background-color/43558934

Comment: @JoopEggen  I have tried this -fx-background-radius but getting rounded corners on the four sides? i only need two sides?!

Comment: the referenced question has a link to the css reference .. you might want to read the paragraph that defines the format :) Hint: you want only two rounded corners, but specify all 4 ..

Comment: @kleopatra Tried that too doesn't work?!

Comment: then edit your question to reflect what you _really_ are doing :)

Comment: Why are you confused that you're getting 4 rounded corners, if you specify the same radius for every corner?

Comment: @fabian in my code it wasn't even applying in the code suggested by JoopEggen I am getting 4 rounded corners.!