# JFXDatePicker change style of current date

Tags: css, javafx-11, jfoenix

Pop-up calender of JFXDatePicker showing current date in "default colour" and rest of dates are in black color. As per my application, I configured default color as blue. So not able to differentiate blue and black much. So I want to change the style of current date.

i.e., I want to change the font color of current date and also highlight it with grey color.

How to achieve this? I am very new to JavaFx. Not able to find much help online. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer after spending many hours in debugging:

```
.today {
    -fx-border-color: grey;
    -fx-border-radius: 40px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 14;
}
```

Resources helped me to find the answer:

- https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/skins/JFXDatePickerContent.java - found today class here
- https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html - leant how to apply different styles
- https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/resources/com/jfoenix/assets/css/controls/jfx-date-picker.css
- [JavaFX - Border radius <-> Background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557722/javafx-border-radius-background-color)
- https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/86b854dc367fb32743810716da5583f7d59208f8/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css
- https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/blob/main/materialfx/src/main/resources/io/github/palexdev/materialfx/css/mfx-datepicker-content.css